# Short story with a piano player on a space station who plays a bunch of old songs and, when asked why, claims he was "possessed by a ghost"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ghost, space-station

This one is a very sketchy memory because the main thrust of it was, I'm pretty sure, based on a misunderstanding. When I was a child, in the late 1980s to the early 1990s, I remember reading a short story from either a book from the local library (Ashland, KY) or from the books on my father's shelves. The protagonist of the story was an entertainer, I think playing a piano and singing, on a space station, and at one point, he gets lost in his music, and has kind of a fugue state where he doesn't remember his actions that night as anything more than a blur. A fellow employee (a waitress at the bar, or a bartender?) tells him that he played a lot of very old songs, and asks him why he did so, and where he learned them. He brushes it off with a statement that he must have been "possessed by a ghost" and at the time, I read that as that he actually was possessed by a ghost (with it seeming to me to be interesting to juxtapose the supernatural and science fiction like that). I might have also been inspired by seeing the cover of *[Carmen Mirandas's Ghost is Haunting Space Station Three](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1025488.Carmen_Miranda_s_Ghost_is_Haunting_Space_Station_Three)* at the library. Which... I don't think I actually ever read it, but I may have to track down a copy to see if there's another reason my brain poked the image back into my head. Anyhow, years later, I came to realize he probably meant it as a figure of speech, but at the time, I genuinely thought he has indeed been possessed by a benign ghost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is reminiscent of the closing pages of *Fool's Run* (1987), by Patricia McKillip. It's a novel, not a short story, but the timing is right:

> The night before you and I first talked. He was in here playing the
> piano. For hours. I'd never seen him like that. He never stopped,
> never spoke... He said later he'd been watching the Underworld orbit
> as he played... It was very odd.
> [...]
> "He doesn't usually do that, then? Play for hours like that." "No." "Like he's doing now?"
> [...]
> The Magician's right hand
> halted. He looked up at Jase, pale, his breathing audible, but showing
> no more surprise than one awakened, but not yet fully awakened, from a
> dream. He said, "It's watching us orbit."

Comment: Oh, good memory.  Though I think Fuzzy's memory is closer to the _start_ of the story, where we start in the club and meet the Magician and Sidney: "A ghost was nesting along with the mice in that piano and crawled out into me tonight, gave itself a good time for four hours, then crawled back to bed."  This is after the Magician played a series of Bach Fugues, the Inventions, the Fourth and Fifth English Suites, and more - and ignored a band that tried to electrocute themselves as a protest and the patrollers showing up to arrest them, and everything else.

Comment: Rereading this it's remarkable how much, even though this is a SF story, the writing is still unmistakably McKillip's.  \*sigh\*

Comment: I think DavidW has the right quote! :-D And I don't remember reading that book at all, but I tried to read a lot of those books as a kid, and didn't always comprehend what I was consuming. Ask me about what happened in elementary school when I decided reading *Battlefield Earth* would make me cool...